# Check if elements are out of order in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to check the elements of a list to see if they are out of order compared to a dictionary.

I have the following code:

```
list = ['jump','double blink']
dictionary = collections.OrderedDict([("wink", 1), ("double blink", 10), 
("close your eyes", 100), ("jump", 1000)])
```

If I check the elements of list it should return `False` because "jump" comes after "double blink" in the dictionary.

At first, I thought I could use a for loop to check if the index of the action in the list is less than the index of the next action in the dictionary.

That would be essentially comparing the position of "jump" from the keys list, which is 3, against the index in the dictionary for the next action from the list (the next item is "double blink", which has an index of 1). So 4 < 1 would return false, but I'm not sure how to call the next item in the for loop without getting a list out of range error.

Comment: why did you remove the exercism tag?  This might be useful to others who are doing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to get the current item and the item next to it(no indices involved, so no worries about `IndexError`), and then [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) with a generator expression would do the rest:

```
>>> lst = ['jump','double blink']
>>> all(dictionary[f] < dictionary[s] for f, s in zip(lst, lst[1:]))
False
>>> lst = d.keys()
>>> all(dictionary[f] < dictionary[s] for f, s in zip(lst, lst[1:]))
True
```

Here `zip()` returns something like this:

```
>>> zip(lst, lst[1:])
[('wink', 'double blink'), ('double blink', 'close your eyes'), ('close your eyes', 'jump')]
```

Another option is to use the [`pairwise` recipe from itertools's recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes), which does exactly the same thing using iterators:

```
>>> from itertools import tee, izip
>>> def pairwise(iterable):
        "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
        a, b = tee(iterable)
        next(b, None)
        return izip(a, b)
... 
>>> all(dictionary[f] < dictionary[s] for f, s in pairwise(lst))
True
>>> list(pairwise(lst))
[('wink', 'double blink'), ('double blink', 'close your eyes'), ('close your eyes', 'jump')]
```

Comment: The question is asking for the list to be in the same order as in the dictionary (that is, insertion order), but this code checks the values in the dict. The example given has values ascending with insertion order so this code gives the right solution for that specific data.

Answer (score 1):

@Ashwini has the right answer but just say if the values were not in any order then you could do something like this.

```
>>> items = ['jump','double blink']
>>> dictionary = collections.OrderedDict([("wink", 400), ("double blink", 10),
("close your eyes", 300), ("jump", 0)])
>>> keys = iter(dictionary)
>>> all(item in keys for item in items)
False
```

Comment: simpler: `all(item in keys for item in items)`

Comment: @Anonymous no that's not equivalent at all. but i dont know if that's your full code or not, submit as an answer maybe so i can have a look?

Comment: it replaces your last line. The observation is that `any(key == item for key in keys)` is the same as `item in keys` (even when keys is a generator).